# zsh recording of input output

Tags: zsh

I would like to keep not just history of my commands, but the output as well.
If I type `ls` then it should append to a file
`~/Desktop% ls

test.jpg

file.txt

whatever.pdf`
Is there anything like that? Or should I try and code this with `preexec()` and all that?

Comment: A couple questions. Do you want to be able to distinguish between information provided in `stdin`, from `stdout` and `stderr`? Or do you literally just want a log of the text exactly as it is displayed in the virtual terminal, with no inherent ability to distinguish between data output by a program on stdout/stderr and data keyed into the terminal via the keyboard or other stdin device?

Comment: yep. just like saving what I see in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a spyshell. A shell that just runs script, and that opens zsh. I cannot find the link, so I made a gist.
Here it is: https://gist.github.com/3791646

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `script` utility, which is pretty ancient and should come preinstalled on most UNIX flavours or Linux distros.

Entering `script session.log` at the shell prompt will drop you into a subshell while recording everything you do — both input and output — to the plaintext file `session.log`. Typing <kbd>^D</kbd> will exist the subshell (as usual).

See the `script(1)` man page for more details.